# Where is the hosts file located in Mediatemple (dv)?

Tags: hosts-file, mediatemple, virtualization

I need to edit the hosts file in my (dv) server. However, the file isn't under /etc. Where do I edit it in Mediatemple?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to all of the resources I can find, specifically the Media Temple knowledge base, the hosts file should be located in the /etc directory.

How are you viewing the servers files? It could be that the hosts file is hidden.

Perhaps you could login via ssh and cd into the /etc directory and run ls.

You may find the following page useful:

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/663/System+Paths#dv_40

Comment: I've already found it. You have to log in as root.